# Unrecognized unicode-math command in TeXstudio although unicode-math.cwl is activated

Tags: texstudio, unicode-math, auto-completion, syntax-highlighting

[image: Screenshot of TeXstudio]

TeXstudio 3.0.4 shows some commands defined by `unicode-math` as 'unrecognized command' and highlights them in red although I've enabled `unicode-math.cwl` and `unicode-math-xetex.cwl` in TeXstudio. All the three commands `\increment`, `\symup` and `\symit` are defined in `unicode-math.cwl` as seen in [this file on GitHub](https://github.com/hubutui/texstudio-cwl/blob/master/unicode-math.cwl). I do not get any errors on compiling with XeLaTeX and get the desired output.

How do I make TeXstudio recognize the commands?

Comment: The built-in cwl for unicode-math now contains these commands